# Style each element in ng-repeat differently

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-digest

I have a `ng-repeat` and inside the `ng-repeat`
 each alternative div has a different `border-color`. So i have used

```
< div ng-repeat="channel in channelList">
    <div ng-style="getBgColor()">
</div
```

*`getBgColor()` is defined as :*

```
         $scope.currentColorIndex = (($scope.currentColorIndex+1) % $scope.radioColors.length);
         $scope.tileColor = $scope.radioColors[$scope.currentColorIndex].hex;
         return $scope.tileColor
```

I keep getting the error

```
$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached
```

I know why i am getting the error, since on every `ng-repeat` iteration i return a different object. What is the work around to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you dont even need to call a function, since **`ng-repeat` records its index using `$index`** you can use it in inner element.

```
<div ng-repeat="channel in channelList">
    <div ng-style="{color: radioColors[$index].hex}">
</div
```

It will assign the `color` property to the hex returned by the `radioColors[$index].hex` expression, where `radioColors` is scope object.

[Just go through this documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 2):

Using [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) allows you to use $index.

```
<div ng-repeat="channel in channelList">
    <div ng-style="getBgColor($index)">
</div>
```